# TikTok pixels getting fired N times where N is the amount of different events involved

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, pixel, facebook-pixel

On the following code I have 6 different pixels I want to fire.

There are just 2 different events involved among all of them: { `SubmitForm`, `Pageview` }.

Then, every time an event is fired, all the events are fired (with the corresponding pixel id, though).

This is the code (where the pixel setup code is the same for all of them).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TikTok Pixels</title>
<script>!function (w, d, t) {
  w.TiktokAnalyticsObject=t;var ttq=w[t]=w[t]||[];ttq.methods=["page","track","identify","instances","debug","on","off","once","ready","alias","group","enableCookie","disableCookie"],ttq.setAndDefer=function(t,e){t[e]=function(){t.push([e].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}};for(var i=0;i<ttq.methods.length;i++)ttq.setAndDefer(ttq,ttq.methods[i]);ttq.instance=function(t){for(var e=ttq._i[t]||[],n=0;n<ttq.methods.length;n++)ttq.setAndDefer(e,ttq.methods[n]);return e},ttq.load=function(e,n){var i="https://analytics.tiktok.com/i18n/pixel/events.js";ttq._i=ttq._i||{},ttq._i[e]=[],ttq._i[e]._u=i,ttq._t=ttq._t||{},ttq._t[e]=+new Date,ttq._o=ttq._o||{},ttq._o[e]=n||{};var o=document.createElement("script");o.type="text/javascript",o.async=!0,o.src=i+"?sdkid="+e+"&lib="+t;var a=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(o,a)};
  ttq.load('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR01');
  ttq.track('SubmitForm');
}(window, document, 'ttq');
</script>
<script>!function (w, d, t) {
  w.TiktokAnalyticsObject=t;var ttq=w[t]=w[t]||[];ttq.methods=["page","track","identify","instances","debug","on","off","once","ready","alias","group","enableCookie","disableCookie"],ttq.setAndDefer=function(t,e){t[e]=function(){t.push([e].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}};for(var i=0;i<ttq.methods.length;i++)ttq.setAndDefer(ttq,ttq.methods[i]);ttq.instance=function(t){for(var e=ttq._i[t]||[],n=0;n<ttq.methods.length;n++)ttq.setAndDefer(e,ttq.methods[n]);return e},ttq.load=function(e,n){var i="https://analytics.tiktok.com/i18n/pixel/events.js";ttq._i=ttq._i||{},ttq._i[e]=[],ttq._i[e]._u=i,ttq._t=ttq._t||{},ttq._t[e]=+new Date,ttq._o=ttq._o||{},ttq._o[e]=n||{};var o=document.createElement("script");o.type="text/javascript",o.async=!0,o.src=i+"?sdkid="+e+"&lib="+t;var a=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(o,a)};
  ttq.load('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR02');
  ttq.page();
}(window, document, 'ttq');
</script>
<script>
!function (w, d, t) {
  w.TiktokAnalyticsObject=t;var ttq=w[t]=w[t]||[];ttq.methods=["page","track","identify","instances","debug","on","off","once","ready","alias","group","enableCookie","disableCookie"],ttq.setAndDefer=function(t,e){t[e]=function(){t.push([e].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}};for(var i=0;i<ttq.methods.length;i++)ttq.setAndDefer(ttq,ttq.methods[i]);ttq.instance=function(t){for(var e=ttq._i[t]||[],n=0;n<ttq.methods.length;n++)ttq.setAndDefer(e,ttq.methods[n]);return e},ttq.load=function(e,n){var i="https://analytics.tiktok.com/i18n/pixel/events.js";ttq._i=ttq._i||{},ttq._i[e]=[],ttq._i[e]._u=i,ttq._t=ttq._t||{},ttq._t[e]=+new Date,ttq._o=ttq._o||{},ttq._o[e]=n||{};var o=document.createElement("script");o.type="text/javascript",o.async=!0,o.src=i+"?sdkid="+e+"&lib="+t;var a=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(o,a)};
  ttq.load('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR03');
  ttq.page();
}(window, document, 'ttq');
</script>
<script>
!function (w, d, t) {
  w.TiktokAnalyticsObject=t;var ttq=w[t]=w[t]||[];ttq.methods=["page","track","identify","instances","debug","on","off","once","ready","alias","group","enableCookie","disableCookie"],ttq.setAndDefer=function(t,e){t[e]=function(){t.push([e].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}};for(var i=0;i<ttq.methods.length;i++)ttq.setAndDefer(ttq,ttq.methods[i]);ttq.instance=function(t){for(var e=ttq._i[t]||[],n=0;n<ttq.methods.length;n++)ttq.setAndDefer(e,ttq.methods[n]);return e},ttq.load=function(e,n){var i="https://analytics.tiktok.com/i18n/pixel/events.js";ttq._i=ttq._i||{},ttq._i[e]=[],ttq._i[e]._u=i,ttq._t=ttq._t||{},ttq._t[e]=+new Date,ttq._o=ttq._o||{},ttq._o[e]=n||{};var o=document.createElement("script");o.type="text/javascript",o.async=!0,o.src=i+"?sdkid="+e+"&lib="+t;var a=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(o,a)};
  ttq.load('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR04');
  ttq.page();
}(window, document, 'ttq');
</script>
<script>
!function (w, d, t) {
  w.TiktokAnalyticsObject=t;var ttq=w[t]=w[t]||[];ttq.methods=["page","track","identify","instances","debug","on","off","once","ready","alias","group","enableCookie","disableCookie"],ttq.setAndDefer=function(t,e){t[e]=function(){t.push([e].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}};for(var i=0;i<ttq.methods.length;i++)ttq.setAndDefer(ttq,ttq.methods[i]);ttq.instance=function(t){for(var e=ttq._i[t]||[],n=0;n<ttq.methods.length;n++)ttq.setAndDefer(e,ttq.methods[n]);return e},ttq.load=function(e,n){var i="https://analytics.tiktok.com/i18n/pixel/events.js";ttq._i=ttq._i||{},ttq._i[e]=[],ttq._i[e]._u=i,ttq._t=ttq._t||{},ttq._t[e]=+new Date,ttq._o=ttq._o||{},ttq._o[e]=n||{};var o=document.createElement("script");o.type="text/javascript",o.async=!0,o.src=i+"?sdkid="+e+"&lib="+t;var a=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(o,a)};
  ttq.load('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR05');
  ttq.page();
}(window, document, 'ttq');
</script>
<script>
!function (w, d, t) {
  w.TiktokAnalyticsObject=t;var ttq=w[t]=w[t]||[];ttq.methods=["page","track","identify","instances","debug","on","off","once","ready","alias","group","enableCookie","disableCookie"],ttq.setAndDefer=function(t,e){t[e]=function(){t.push([e].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}};for(var i=0;i<ttq.methods.length;i++)ttq.setAndDefer(ttq,ttq.methods[i]);ttq.instance=function(t){for(var e=ttq._i[t]||[],n=0;n<ttq.methods.length;n++)ttq.setAndDefer(e,ttq.methods[n]);return e},ttq.load=function(e,n){var i="https://analytics.tiktok.com/i18n/pixel/events.js";ttq._i=ttq._i||{},ttq._i[e]=[],ttq._i[e]._u=i,ttq._t=ttq._t||{},ttq._t[e]=+new Date,ttq._o=ttq._o||{},ttq._o[e]=n||{};var o=document.createElement("script");o.type="text/javascript",o.async=!0,o.src=i+"?sdkid="+e+"&lib="+t;var a=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(o,a)};
  ttq.load('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR06');
  ttq.page();
}(window, document, 'ttq');
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Just Firing TikTok Pixels</h2>
<h3>...on the background</h3>

</body>
</html>
```

After the page loads, and the pixels are fired we can see the following on the Developer Tools:

[image]

```
[ 1] pixel -> payload: { ..., event: "SubmitForm", ... }
[ 2] pixel -> payload: { ..., event: "Pageview", ... }
[ 3] pixel -> payload: { ..., event: "SubmitForm", ... }
[ 4] pixel -> payload: { ..., event: "Pageview", ... }
[ 5] pixel -> payload: { ..., event: "SubmitForm", ... }
[ 6] pixel -> payload: { ..., event: "Pageview", ... }
[ 7] pixel -> payload: { ..., event: "SubmitForm", ... }
[ 8] pixel -> payload: { ..., event: "Pageview", ... }
[ 9] pixel -> payload: { ..., event: "SubmitForm", ... }
[10] pixel -> payload: { ..., event: "Pageview", ... }
[11] pixel -> payload: { ..., event: "SubmitForm", ... }
[12] pixel -> payload: { ..., event: "Pageview", ... }
```

Comment: This behaviour sounds reasonable.
Is there a question here, though?

I did find this useful - I was wondering what would happen in such case